# How to change first column in bootstrap the distance from left?

Tags: css

I'm using Bootstrap and I want to change first column the distance from left. This is illustrated in this picture:

[image]

My code:

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">A Basic Panel</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">.col-sm-7</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">.col-sm-1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I try with margin-left, padding-left, but I don't found where it's need change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
<div class="container">
```

to

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23360/

Answer (score 2):

The `.container` class adds a max width to that element, and centers it on the page. If you want `col-sm-1` all the way to the left, you'll want to remove/adjust how you're using the `.container` class.

On top of that, `.row` and `.col-sm-*` come with some additional margin/paddings. Try using chrome inspector to look at your elements on the page and see how/why they are laid out the way they are.